# Install CLSQL on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clsql

I have SBCL installed (via macports/darwinports) on my Intel Core 2 Duo Macbook running 10.5.8.  I've installed several libraries like this:

```
(require 'asdf)
(require 'asdf-install)
(asdf-install:install 'cl-who)
```

But when I tried to install CLSQL this way (`'clsql`) after it downloaded, I got this:

```
...
; registering #<SYSTEM CLSQL-UFFI {123D9E01}> as CLSQL-UFFI
; $ cd /Users/ken/.sbcl/site/clsql-5.0.5/uffi/; make
cc -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -bundle /usr/lib/bundle1.o -flat_namespace -undefined suppress clsql_uffi.c -o clsql_uffi.dylib
ld: duplicate symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper in /usr/lib/bundle1.o and /usr/lib/bundle1.o for architecture i386
ld: duplicate symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper in /usr/lib/bundle1.o and /usr/lib/bundle1.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/Nf/Nf4o5ArDFaWBH2OwtnWM3E+++TQ/-Tmp-//ccJyZxou.out (No such file or directory)
make: *** [clsql_uffi.so] Error 1
```

Is there something I forgot, or some trick to get it to build on Mac OS X?  I know very little about C libraries on the Mac these days, so I don't even know where to start on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Btw, have you tried quicklisp to handle instalations?

Comment: Should be noted `asdf-install` is considered deprecated at this point. I was able to use `quicklisp` to resolve a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a lot easier to use Quicklisp insteak of a "naked" ASDF. Take a look at https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions [here](http://clsql.b9.com/manual/installation.html), have you done all of the preparation steps?

Answer (score 0):

Progress: inspired by [this Asterisk bug report](https://issues.asterisk.org/view.php?id=16449) ("Including bundle1.o breaks Tiger and Leopard"), I removed `-bundle /usr/lib/bundle1.o` from all 4 places in `~/.sbcl/site/clsql-5.1.1/uffi/Makefile` and reinstalled, and it got further before dying.

I'm now seeing:

```
debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread #<THREAD "initial thread" RUNNING {1193E621}>:
  Couldn't load foreign library "clsql_uffi". (searched CLSQL-SYS:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS*)
```

This is kind of bizarre, since:

- `clsql-sys:*foreign-library-search-paths*` is `(#P"/Users/ken/.sbcl/site/clsql-5.1.1/uffi/")`
- `clsql-uffi-loader.lisp` tries all of `(uffi:foreign-library-types)`, which is `("dylib" "bundle")`
- there is a `~/.sbcl/site/clsql-5.1.1/uffi/clsql_uffi.dylib` file built by the makefile

Ideas?

Comment: *A comment from an anonymous user added as an edit:*

FIX:

The related problem seems to be caused by the fact that the actual .dylib files although created are not real dynamic shared libraries. For this, when removing -bundle /usr/lib/bundle1.o add -dynamiclib to those same lines.